# calendar, exporting Outlook emails to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, email

My job is to export emails from Outlook default inbox folder to CSV file.

Here is the script:

```
cls
Function Get-OutlookInBox   #getoutlookcontent
{ 

Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
$folder.items |  
Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, SenderName, to
} 

write-host "select date greater or equal to and hit enter"
Function date1                                                        
#calendar
{
[void] 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(190,190) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {
        $global:dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 


}

date1

$gt = (get-date).tostring()              #getcurrent date

Get-OutlookInbox |                        #exporting
where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime] "$globa:dtmdate" -AND $_.ReceivedTime 
-le 
[datetime] "$gt" } | Export-Csv D:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test1.csv -
Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation -force
```

Parts of code are works perfectly fine separately.
I am able export emails when i am putting date in to code like that:

```
Get-OutlookInbox |                        #exporting
where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime] "8/21/2017" -AND $_.ReceivedTime 
-le 
[datetime] "8/24/2017" } | Export-Csv D:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test1.csv -
Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation -force
```

but while I am trying to put variable instead of exact values I am getting error msg Cannot convert value "" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

My question is how to convert variable in to datetime.

Second thing which I notice in this part of code

```
Get-OutlookInbox |                        #exporting
where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime] "8/21/2017" -AND $_.ReceivedTime 
-le 
[datetime] "8/24/2017" } | Export-Csv D:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test1.csv -
Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation -force
```

In that case operator `-gt` works perfectly fine for me even it shouldn't. Script exporting emails from date which I set not day after. But second part `-le` works like less than not less and equal. Which is confusing since I need to set date day+1. I have tried to put several comparison operators but result is always the same.

Comment: You should show us an example of how you are trying to incorporate variables in to the code. It's hard to tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: The reason your `-gt` part isn't working as you expect is because [datetime]"8/21/2017" sets a date of midnight on the 21st august. So any emails sent on that day will be included (e.g if they were sent at 00:00:01 on the 21st August they would be included). Same with the `-le`, is only a match if the email was received before or exactly on midnight of the 24th August.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the exact code that caused the error you shared already.

Comment: Before I was trying to get date using read-host and put 8/24/2017 in to, but I get to the point that I can use calendar instead of read-host to set variable. But still calendar output is is stored in $global:dtmDate just like read-host and I am getting same error msg as before.

Comment: I need to see the exact code that causes your error to help you.